# Proper pagination with rel=next/prev tags

Tags: html, seo

My site has two basic types of pages:

1. A list page, with lists of items. Each item drives to #2, a detail page.
2. The detail page. One piece of content from a section, like "News" or "Blog Posts". Sometimes, these detail pages are paginated, e.g., "Page 1 of A Long List".

I'm very confused about how rel=next/prev is implemented.

1. Should I be using prev/next for showing Google that a page is "Page 1 of All Blog Posts" and "next" is "Page 2 of All Blog Posts"? Or should I exclude them from my list pages?
2. For single-page detail pages, should I be using rel=prev/next to link to the next and previous detail pages from the set?
3. For multi-page detail pages, I know that I should link pages with prev/next tags, but what should the last page have? It would seem that using next/prev on the last page of a paginated detail page could be misleading to crawlers.

Thanks!

Comment: Frankly, I doubt that crawlers care at all. What use would the information be to them?

Comment: @Alohci: Actually, Google does care: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html

Comment: @MattSach - Interesting, thanks. But note that I didn't say Google doesn't care, I said crawlers don't care. It's the indexer that's using the information, not the crawler.

Comment: @Alohci: Yes, you're correct. I made the mistake of assuming "crawler" was a synonym for the entire crawl/index machinery. Now I've read more of your other q/a/c entries, I see you're someone who can be (and usually is) specific about such things :)

Answer (score 2):

1. It may be you don't need to do anything at all. If the content within the series tends to stay put, the URLs are numbered, etc., Google's probably working it out for itself.
2. Don't use prev/next between single-page pages. The idea with prev/next is that a single piece of content which stretches over multiple pages is treated as a whole, so applying it to single-page pieces of content, even if they can be considered as part of some group or set, would be to their detriment.
3. First page in a series only has the `"next"` tag, last page only has the `"prev"` tag. All the rest have both.

And incidentally, if your pagination is done with parameters, you have an alternative in that you can use Google Webmaster Tools to inform Googlebot how to handle your pagination.

Answer (score -2):

If you find anything confusing in the article(link below) than just let us know. And if you completely understand the article and the article about "view all"(link in the article) than I think your problem is solved.

[Pagination with rel='next' and rel='prev'](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.in/2011/09/pagination-with-relnext-and-relprev.html)